# Can't add or subtract products with 1 item in stock - gettin a textStatus:'error' - Prestashop

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics, prestashop, cart

I have been having this problem for a week almost in my Prestashop 1.6.0.13.

 My question is that when I go to Prestashop Men's section and try to add products to cart (with 1 item in stock).

 I have enabled the option for advanced stock management but it didn't seem to help me out on my problem.
 I get the next following message:

> "Impossible to add the product to the cart 
>  textStatus:error 
>   errorThrown
>  responseText;"

The weird thing is that when I try to refresh the product item, it appears on my cart. The same happens when I subtract the product from my cart. 

 
From the other side, it doesn't seem to be a problem for the rest of categories.
I double checked the URLs also to see if there was a conflict between friendly URL's and cart but I deem that the problem doesn't lie there.
I disabled the Ajax cart also to see if the problem lied there but no solution either. Currently, I am using the default Prestashop cart block.

I found a way solving the problem by uninstalling Google Analytics module but it isn't what I really want for solution because I need it in order to make reports on statistics.

Has anybody encountered any similar problem and found a solution ?

Please, if you have any suggestions on solving this matter, I would be really glad.

Thanks,

Orestis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok the solution was to remove "|" from every product description in Back-Office, which was the source of the problem. The products that had it, was creating a PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Forbidden chars in cookie' in /var/sites/c/caneihavethis.com/public_html/classes/Cookie.php:169.
I wouldn't recommend though to edit the Cookie.php line. Just by removing this char, Google Analytics won't give problems in adding or subtracting a product.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I would have wasted so much time trying to locate this problem.

Answer (score 1):

On pressing `Add to cart` button it sends data and gets a response in `JSON` format. In your site there is a syntax error in that response.

It is not easy to find the reason and fix it. But you can:

- If you have experienced that uninstalling `Google Analytics` module is fixing it - you must be sure you have configured it properly or you should try to use another module. Though the problem can not necessary be related directly...
- *Advanced*. Use `Firefox` `Firebug` addon and check in its *Console* what is the full response on pressing `Add to cart`. It shows more information about what is causing this error.

  You can find many tutorials how to use `Firefox` `Firebug`, it is quite simple. You can find the reason, uninstall buggy modules or themes, but it is possible you need to get a help from a coder to fix it finally.

  [image: Where to check in Firefox Firebug]
- Get a help from a coder.

Comment: Hey there! I get the next message when I open the Firebug add-on and open the "panel of the problem". It is derived from here: `controller=cart&ajax=true&delete=true&summary=true&id_product=1888&ipa=0&id_address_delivery=0&token
=84c6ff173c9f6a44a123f5fd37a38382&allow_refresh=1`. I will need to check the frontcontroller.php file for the ajax cart. Maybe the problem it is hidden there.

Comment: The file `classes/controller/FrontController.php` if you meant it is not related with your problem as it is used by ALL pages classes and ALL modules. 
Most likely your issue is related with one of the modules or your theme files.
The file which is getting JSON error (but not producing it) is themes/[your-theme]/js/modules/blockcart/ajax-cart.js.

Comment: Can you try enter and buy a product from the site just to confirm if it is possible to add or remove products from the cart? Now it is working ok. Check: `http://caneihavethis.com/en/`

Comment: Yes, `Add to cart` in your site is working, though there are multiple `javascript` errors related with Google Maps, unconfigured Amazon module.

Comment: Just uninstalled the Amazon module. I won't be needing it. I don't get any more javascript errors. The thing is not there. I think it is what you said. And I don't think that is really related with Analytics either because only one category (Men's category) has that problem. The rest is working fine. I think it has to be some problem of encoding with the id of every one of those products.

Comment: Oh sorry, haven't checked your site "Mens" category... I guess you have modified your theme files and I still see `javascript` (and `css` added anywhere) errors. But the `Add to cart` is not working because you have an incorrect category page template and _for the products with no combinations_ it is not working.

Comment: I have been checking the categories in the Back-Office and the weird thing is I can't locate nowhere those items. That is really weird. Incorrect category page template? What do you mean by that?

Comment: If you see errors in the BackOffice (sorry, I haven't got what do you mean by _can't locate nowhere those items_) - you are in a trouble. First of all you need to be sure everything in your BackOffice and database is Ok.
Category page template is your `themes/[your-theme]/category.tpl`, `themes/[your-theme]/js/category.js`, `controllers/front/CategoryController.php` and all dependent files included in code.
I see this issue is related to your site only and has a little value to StackOverflow community :) Please ask a coder to help you.

Comment: I can't locate the items that are inside the Men's location (T-shirts, Sweaters-Hoddies,etc). I have some knowledge about coding but not that much in order to fix this issue because there are many scripting languages entangled in Prestashop's framework. I will check on my category files and probably I will seek some assistance to a Prestashop forum. Maybe there I can find a solution. Thanks though for the updates. cheers

Comment: In your BackOffice go to `Catalog > Categories`, get the list of categories, press `View` at the right of a category - you will see its subcategories.